# Machine Learning in GATE

Tags: machine-learning, gate

In GATE machine learning module 11, they have used an annotation set called 'Key', which has been manually prepared. when I applied that ML technique on my corpus, it didn't work. my data set does not have annotation set name, instead it has a default 'Original markups' name which is not been recognized by JAPE Transducer --> inputAsName property. How to give my annotation set a name so that it can process ML?

I followed this GATE tutorial http://gate.ac.uk/sale/talks/gate-course-may11/track-3/module-11-machine-learning/module-11.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I just followed the same instructions, creating a blank corpus, and populating from the corpus folder in [the sample materials](https://gate.ac.uk/sale/talks/gate-course-may11/track-3/module-11-machine-learning/module-11-hands-on.zip) they provide. It worked fine for me, I can see the `Key` annotations set by opening one of the documents and clicking the `annotations sets` button.

Did you populate a blank corpus by right clicking, populate, and then selecting the folder containing the course files?

Comment: Yes, I did the way you populated the corpus but still not getting any KEY annotation set.

Comment: I am not working on their sample data set instead I'm using my own data set that's why the problem is occurring. Please help if you know.

Comment: Ah I see. So you have an 'Original' annotation set already in the documents and you want to use this as a training set? There is a processing resource called 'Annotation set transfer' which allows you to copy an annotation set and assign it a name. You would input the original markup, and choose your output name. Then you might be able to proceed.

Comment: ...and, based on your initial comment, I'll just check that you realise the 'Key' annotation set is not produced automatically on any corpus. It is only present in the sample data because the Gate team put it there. You won't have a Key annotation set unless you create one.

Comment: I have seen 'Annotation set transfer PR' but don't know how to use it in GATE as its plugin is not built-in. If you know any useful link of doing that or any technique kindly share it with me.